# what's wrong with this simple fetch PDO statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, fetch

What's wrong with this PDO code? It doesn't give me any results although there definitely are some results in the `tip` table in the database.

```
try{
    $this->pdo = new PDO( "mysql:host=".zConfig::read('hostname').";dbname=".zConfig::read('database'), zConfig::read('username'), zConfig::read('password'),  zConfig::read('drivers'));
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT tip_text FROM tip WHERE product_id=:product_id AND item LIKE :which");
        $stmt->execute(array(':product_id'   => $id, ':which' => $which  ));

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($row['tip_text']!='') echo $row['tip_text'];
            else echo "";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)  
    {  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();   }
```

And where can I print out the final query that the PDO executes? (parameters included)? The variables `$id` and `$which` are correctly populated from above.

Comment: As for printing out the actual filled-in query, you might have to check the mysql logs; if PDO does a real prepare instead of emulating one, the query wouldn't be filled in by PDO, but by the DBMS.  Even if it emulated a prepare, though, i don't know of any way to obtain the actual query sent.

Comment: One of the ways that really helps me debug my applications is echoing out my queries during development, by using PDO can I no longer have that convenience?

Comment: What do you get doing a var_dump($row)?

Comment: That's not a PDO issue; it's a (slight) drawback of prepared statements.  Any library you use that offers them, if it actually prepares a statement, will likely have the same problem.  The whole point of them is that the SQL and the data are separated, ideally the whole time, and the DBMS combines them at the end.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa, I get `bool(false)`. <scratches head>

Comment: @user961627: If you haven't gotten an exception before that point, the query was successful and simply returned no rows.

Comment: it does return rows when I run the SQL directly on the database :S

Comment: Odd.  I'd do a `var_dump($id, $which)` right before the execute, and make sure the right values are being used.

Comment: What is your error message?Did you try hard coding parameters to your query?